# How to include a wxObjArray correctly?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, wxwidgets

I define a wxObjArray in my `TMainFrame.h` as follows:

```
#ifndef __TMainFrame__
#define __TMainFrame__

#include "MyApp_gui.h"
//// end generated include

#include "TRunThread.h"

#include <wx/dynarray.h>

class TMove;

WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY(TMove, TMoveArray);

/* ...Class TMainFrame... */
/* ...Class TMove... */

#endif // __TMainFrame__
```

Now I want to use the class TMoveArray created by WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY in my `TRunThread.h`.
But that class cannot be found (GCC: *'TMoveArray' has not been declared*)

```
#ifndef TRUNTHREAD_H_INCLUDED
#define TRUNTHREAD_H_INCLUDED

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "TMainFrame.h"

// doesn't work: WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY(TMove, TMoveArray);

class TRunThread : public wxThread
{
  public:
    wxThreadError Create(TMoveArray moves);
};

#endif // TRUNTHREAD_H_INCLUDED
```

The source file `TRunThread.cpp`:

```
#include <wx/arrimpl.cpp> // this is a magic incantation which must be done!
WX_DEFINE_OBJARRAY(TMoveArray);
#include "TRunThread.h"

/* ...Code... */
```

I've also tried with the `WX_DEFINE_OBJARRAY` directive.

**Question:** How to include a wxObjArray correctly?

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? Have you read the dynarray.h about how to use WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY - you have not mentioned arrimpl.cpp?

Comment: I've updated my post. I include arrimpl.cpp in my source files (TMainFrame.cpp and TRunThread.cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need both `WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY` and `WX_DEFINE_OBJARRAY`. The latter goes to an implementation file.

The [reference](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_array_3_01_t_01_4.html) has a full usage example and more comments.

---

And you might also just use `std::vector`.

Comment: In the source file, right? I have already put that two lines into TRunThread.cpp (see my post again).

I also think std::vector is a bit simplier than wxObjArray.

Comment: If I put WX_DECLARE_OBJARRAY into both header files, I get a 'redefinition' error.

The code compiled correctly until I've created TRunThread.cpp/h which also needs that array!

Comment: The reference mentions that `<wx/arrimpl.cpp> ` needs to be included **before** the define macro.

Comment: See my code, I include at first `<wx/arrimpl.cpp>`, then I execute the  macro and at last I include the header file `TRunThread.h`.

Comment: It looks like you have a circular inclusion between the two headers. - You might get rid of the `#include "TRunThread.h"`.